# Programa cronómetro en Java: ¿Cómo guardar en un archivo txt los tiempos cada vez que se detenga el cronómetro?

Tags: java, txt

Estoy usando este programa cronómetro en Java y todo funciona correctamente: el tiempo corre, se pude pausar y se puede detener/resetear. Pero ahora lo que quiero hacer es que cuando yo le dé al botón de detener el tiempo del cronómetro, el tiempo que se haya quedado se almacene en un archivo txt y que la siguiente vez se guarde en el mismo txt que el anterior. Es decir, que en un mismo txt esté el registro de todos los tiempos que han habido.

El caso es que no sabría cómo hacerlo y necesito ayuda. Aquí paso mi código a ver.

```
package clases;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 * @author JCarlos;
 */
public class Cronometro extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Cronometro() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        t = new Timer(10, acciones);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        etiquetaReloj = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        etiquetaTitulo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        etiquetaTiempo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnStart = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnPause = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnStop = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("CronÃ³metro - ProgramaciÃ³n y mÃ¡s !");

        etiquetaReloj.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/reloj.png"))); // NOI18N

        etiquetaTitulo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Corbel", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        etiquetaTitulo.setText("CronÃ³metro");

        etiquetaTiempo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Sans", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        etiquetaTiempo.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        etiquetaTiempo.setText("00:00:00:00");

        btnStart.setText("Iniciar");
        btnStart.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnStartActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnPause.setText("Pausar");
        btnPause.setEnabled(false);
        btnPause.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnPauseActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnStop.setText("Detener");
        btnStop.setEnabled(false);
        btnStop.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnStopActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(etiquetaReloj)
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(etiquetaTiempo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(etiquetaTitulo)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(btnStart, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(btnPause, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(btnStop, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(etiquetaTitulo)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(etiquetaTiempo)
                        .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(btnStart)
                            .addComponent(btnPause)
                            .addComponent(btnStop)))
                    .addComponent(etiquetaReloj))
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private Timer t;
    private int h, m, s, cs;
    private ActionListener acciones = new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            ++cs; 
            if(cs==100){
                cs = 0;
                ++s;
            }
            if(s==60) 
            {
                s = 0;
                ++m;
            }
            if(m==60)
            {
                m = 0;
                ++h;
            }
            actualizarLabel();
        }
        
    };
    
    private void actualizarLabel() {
        String tiempo = (h<=9?"0":"")+h+":"+(m<=9?"0":"")+m+":"+(s<=9?"0":"")+s+":"+(cs<=9?"0":"")+cs;
        etiquetaTiempo.setText(tiempo);
    }
    
    private void btnStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnStartActionPerformed
        t.start();
        btnStart.setEnabled(false);
        btnStart.setText("Reanudar");
        btnPause.setEnabled(true);
        btnStop.setEnabled(true);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnStartActionPerformed

    private void btnPauseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnPauseActionPerformed
        t.stop();
        btnStart.setEnabled(true);
        btnPause.setEnabled(false);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnPauseActionPerformed

    private void btnStopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnStopActionPerformed
        if(t.isRunning()) 
        {
            t.stop();
            btnStart.setEnabled(true);
        }
        btnStart.setText("Iniciar");
        btnPause.setEnabled(false);
        btnStop.setEnabled(false);
        h=0; m=0; s=0; cs=0;
        actualizarLabel();
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnStopActionPerformed


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Cronometro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Cronometro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Cronometro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Cronometro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Cronometro().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton btnPause;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnStart;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnStop;
    private javax.swing.JLabel etiquetaReloj;
    private javax.swing.JLabel etiquetaTiempo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel etiquetaTitulo;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Comment: Puedes dividir tu problema en partes mas sencillas, primero aprender como crear un fichero txt, luego como abirlo, leerlo, modificarlo y por ultimo y muy importante cerrarlo. Una vez que sabes como manejar ficheros lo siguiente que tienes que hacer es realizar dichas operaciones cuando le das al boton de detener. Con una simple busqueda en google puedes encontrar varios ejemplos ==> [Google](https://geekytheory.com/como-crear-y-modificar-ficheros-con-java)

Comment: Vale, ya he probado y me sale bien lo de crear, escribir un archivo, etc. Pero lo que sigo sin poder saber es cómo hacer que se escriban en los archivos txt los tiempos cada vez que le doy al botón de detener. He escrito algo parecido al tutorial que has pasado en la parte de este botón del código pero, aunque sí me crea el archivo, no sé cómo hacer para que el tiempo se escriba ahí. Estoy usando BufferedWriter y PrintWriter pero hasta ahí más no sé.

Comment: Los tipos de datos ara tiempo no son serializables, debes usar un formateador para serializar y deserializar de archivo.